# Windows command line - disable all outgoing traffic

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, firewall, windows-firewall

I want to be able to disable all outgoing traffic but not incoming traffic - something like `netsh interface set interface "Ethernet" disable` but only for outgoing traffic. How do I do that from the windows command line?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). If there is no outbound traffic then there will be no replies to any inbound traffic which is kind of pointless. What are you actually trying to achieve?.

Comment: I'm writing a multiplayer game in unity and testing it for weather various hack methods are effective so that I can fix them. Simply disabling the network for a time (to use as a "lag switch") was too impracticle to be a problem because they would have no information about the game while it happened. However, I also want to test for just not sending updates while still receiving info. I could access the lower levels of the multiplayer library to do it but it seems easier (and more realistic) to do it this way.

Comment: So the players would essentially see a frozen screen? That means they would still have no "information about the game while it happened" because you are not sending anything. I think you need to rethink your testing strategy.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your comments, I'll assume you want something for UDP, as a one-way TCP connection is rather useless.

The best way to do this is with a firewall. The built-in Windows Firewall can be used here.

It's easiest to use PowerShell to manipulate the firewall, rather than the legacy command line.

You can create a new rule with [`New-NetFirewallRule`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps). For example:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block all outbound traffic" -Direction Outbound -Action Block
```

Add `-Protocol UDP` and use `-RemotePort` or `-RemoteAddress` to further restrict the rule.

You can also create the rule using the GUI.

You can then toggle the rule using [`Enable-NetFirewallRule`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/enable-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps) and [`Disable-NetFirewallRule`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/disable-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps), e.g.:

```
Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block all outbound traffic"
```

and

```
Disable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Block all outbound traffic"
```